# How to create SQL query with multiple conditions in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Please help me with the following syntax. Something it s wrong on it...

I have two tables, table 1 Readers and table 2 Loans.

I want to return all the info about the `readerID` for the `readerid` who has max from NB_Readers...

```
SELECT Surname, Name, Phone, Address, E-mail 
FROM Readers 
INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 * 
            FROM
                (SELECT ReaderID, COUNT (readerID) as NB_Readers
                 FROM Loans AS W
                 WHERE (YEAR(loans.datefrom) = 2018 
                   AND YEAR(loans.dateto) = 2018)
                 GROUP BY readerid)
            ORDER BY NB_Readers DESC) ON Readers.ReaderID = W.ReaderID
```

Comment: Please tag your DBMS (version included)

Comment: "something is wrong with it" -- is this a quiz? What's wrong? What is your code doing or not doing that it shouldn't be doing or should be doing?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is one of scope: in your outermost join clause, you are referencing the table `W`, however, this alias is assigned within your innermost nested `SELECT` query and will not exist outside of this query.

The simplest modification to enable your code to work would be to move the alias assignment from your nested `SELECT` query to the query that you are joining with your `Readers` table, i.e.:

```
SELECT Surname, Name, Phone, Address, E-mail 
FROM Readers 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT ReaderID, COUNT (ReaderID) as NB_Readers
        FROM Loans
        WHERE (YEAR(datefrom) = 2018 AND YEAR(dateto) = 2018)
        GROUP BY ReaderID
    )
    ORDER BY NB_Readers DESC
) AS W
ON Readers.ReaderID = W.ReaderID
```